# ば　ほど with 2 different verbs; 気持ちの持ちよう

Tags: grammar, words, expressions

> **作業と思わなければ動けなくなるほど**切迫していたが、とにもかくにも精神的なダメージは負わなくなった。
>   だが、これだけは**気持ちの持ちようなどでは耐えられない**。
>
> She is pressured by the fact that the more she does not think about this as a job, the more she becomes unable to move.
>   At any rate the emotional damage is disappeared.
>   But, she cannot sustain this situation by maintaining her feelings.(or with her attitude, way of thinking)

I have 2 questions.

1.V1ばV1ほど=The more V

2.V1ばV2ほど=What does this mean?
  I think "the more V1 the more V2...", but I am not sure.
  Another way I think it could be is "When V1, to the degree of V2....".

The other problem is:

> 気持ちの持ちよう

I found online
気の持ちよう=考え方次第
But can't find a definition for 気持ちの持ちよう 
other than
[Meaning of 気持ちの持ち方まで問題にしている](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/5526/meaning-of-%E6%B0%97%E6%8C%81%E3%81%A1%E3%81%AE%E6%8C%81%E3%81%A1%E6%96%B9%E3%81%BE%E3%81%A7%E5%95%8F%E9%A1%8C%E3%81%AB%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6%E3%81%84%E3%82%8B)

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 作業と思わなければ動けなくなるほど切迫していた

You can forget the "the more ～ the more ～" pattern for now. This is a plain old conditional ば you already know. 「作業と思わなければ動けなくなる」 literally means "If she doesn't think (of it) as a task, she won't be able to move." And "～ほど切迫していた" can be translated as "She was so pressured that ～" or "She was pressured to the point where ～."

So she's faced with something very meaningless or disgusting, and she could not accomplish it without thinking it as a mere task assigned to her.

> これだけは気持ちの持ちようなどでは耐えられない。

- 気持ちの持ちよう ≒ 気持ちの持ち方 ≒ a way of thinking, frame of mind
- など implies 気持ちの持ちよう is unimportant.
- で ≒ by means of

The sentence roughly means "Changing the way of thinking doesn't help her bear this time" or "This one is unbearable no matter what she thinks of it."